# How to get a parent folder on Windows Store App(Windows Runtime)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, storage

I would like to look into whether StorageFolder and StorageFile have a parent folder and get the data if it has on Windows Store App project.

I found "getParentAsync" method at MSDN. However, it seems that this works only Windows 8.1.

Please tell me how to realize the same process as this on Windows 8.0 project.

Comment: Not 100% this will work, but have you tried parsing the `Path` of the `StorageFolder`, then removing the last token? /One/Two/, split on '/', remove the last entry, recreate the path. If the folder that was given to you is user-selected, you may not be able to do this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in 8.0 there is no way to get the Parent of a Folder. I imagine the reasoning is that it would be a way to move out of the folder you were given access to by the user through the FolderPicker etc.

In fact in 8.1 GetParentAsync may fail if you don't have permission to that folder. In apps where I need to get access to a parent folder it's because the user has moved down through a folder structure and is now moving back up. I end up maintaining my own navigation stack of folders.

Comment: I will do string manipulation with the separate charactor when its path can be got. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(...);`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".